# Driver-side power windows wont work, and car keeps unlocking itself

Tags: chevrolet, power-windows, keyless-entry, aveo

I have a Chevy Aveo 2018. Few days ago, my driver side windows stopped working (won't respond to clicking the roll button). In addition, the "a door is open" light on my dashboard stays on, although all my doors (include fuel tank door, and the trunks) are closed. When I leave the car, I use the key fob to lock my car, then a second later it unlocks itself.

Other windows (passengers) work just fine when I click there buttons?

What could the issue likely be?

Comment: Did you check the hood latch?  My older Aveo has a switch on the hood too that sets the "Door Open" light.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by checking the door wiring and control per the electrical manual.  While your car is relatively new and this is usually an old car problem, it's possible that the wiring harness to the door has been damaged.